# Apache htpasswd ignored DomJudge

Tags: apache-2.2, authentication, htpasswd

I am trying to set up DomJudge with Apache on an Ubuntu server and have the following config included in my httpd.conf

```
# Require authentication to jury webinterface
<Directory /home/domjudge/domjudge/domserver/www/jury>
Options Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks 
AuthType Basic
AuthName "DOMjudge Jury Interface Login"
Require valid-user
AuthUserFile /home/domjudge/domjudge/domserver/etc/htpasswd-jury
AllowOverride None 

# Optionally restrict access to just the jury computers:
allow from all
# allow from 192.168.1.0/24
```

And the htpasswd file is as follows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 domjudge www-data   46 2012-04-18 17:14 htpasswd-jury
```

And contains

```
domjudge_jury:OS7*SNIP*T20
Pezmc:Password
```

I restart Apache, when I go to that address I am prompted with a login `this server requires a username and a password`...`the server says DOMjudge Jury Interface Login` but even if I enter the passwords as above the prompt simply comes up again.

What is going on? Have I missed something?

Thanks for your time,

Comment: You didn't specify how you created or obtained that htpasswd-jury file.

Comment: Might want to set the proper permissions on the passwd file as well, `chmod 0644 htpasswd-jury`.

Comment: @Tim I created that file myself conforming to the .htpasswd spec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't have encrypted passwords in your htpasswd-jury file. Just to check things out make a copy of your  `/home/domjudge/domjudge/domserver/etc/htpasswd-jury` file then

```
htpasswd -c /home/domjudge/domjudge/domserver/etc/htpasswd-jury domjudge_jury
```

answer the prompts etc. Now try and log in.

From the apache [htpasswd documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/htpasswd.html)

```
-p
    Use plaintext passwords. Though htpasswd will support creation on all 
platforms, the httpd daemon will only accept plain text passwords on Windows, 
Netware and TPF.
```

As you appear to be on a Unix like system it appears you'll have to use encrypted passwords.

Comment: <3 completely forgot you had to encrypt them...